# How to get a type from a string?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, casting

Why does `var type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox");` return `null`?

I am trying to get the type of a `TextBox` type from a `string`.

Comment: can't you just use regular expression on the String?

Comment: @PatrickHofman my bad, I thought he wanted the name of the class as "String".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include the full assembly name too:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

Note the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) (emphasis mine):

> The **assembly-qualified name** of the type to get. ... If the type is in the **currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll**, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

So only mscorlib and the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` can be resolved using the type name only, else you need the full assembly name too.

Answer (score 4):

You should also include the assembly name and public tokens, etc:

```
var type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```